# how to know the current view controller is on a navigation stack but not the root one

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller

Currently I'm using the following code to find out if a view controller is in the navigation stack, and it's not the root one in the stack.

```
self.navigationController.viewControllers.count > 1
```

Is there any better solutions?

Comment: This solution is good enough I think~

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you convert what you describe directly to code, it'll be something like this.

```
NSUInteger index = [self.navigationController.viewControllers indexOfObject:self];
BOOL b = index != NSNotFound && index != 0;
```

The code you wrote may not work when your `UINavigationController` is not at the top of the stack.

Answer (score 1):

[self.navigationController popToViewController:[self.navigationController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:([self.navigationController.viewControllers count]-2)] animated:YES];